# page.waitForFunction not recognizing page function arguments

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I wrote the following function

```
async function getMatches(page, eventCount) {
    
    await page.waitForFunction((eventCount) => {
            let newCount = document.querySelectorAll('ms-event.grid-event').length
            console.log(eventCount) // this logs as '#document' on the chromium console!
            if (eventCount != newCount) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
    }, {}, eventCount)
}

// function call
await getMatches(page, 0)
```

where evenCount is a number. This is supposed to wait for new grid elements to load and only resolve when they do (newCount would then be different to the eventCount passed as input).

However, the function does not even recognize eventCount as input and logs it as the whole html document (inside the chromium console).

This makes the function resolve instantly and not wait for new elements to load.

Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] that shows where you've defined `eventCount`?

Comment: I edited the code in the original post, hopefully now it's clearer.
Note that I get the same #document problem whether I pass in the number through the eventCount variable or an actual number directly

Comment: I see no reason this shouldn't work, so it's still unreproducible. What Puppeteer version are you running before and after your reinstall you mentioned [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70516930/6243352)?

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled puppeteer and now it's working properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).